# Get All the open applications, files(txt, xlsx etc), , window explorer , web browser tabs

Tags: java, windows, process, wmi, win32-process

I am trying to make an application in java to capture all the open applications, files(txt, xlsx etc), , window explorer , web browser tabs information so that I can reopen same windows at later point of time.

I tried org.jutils.jprocesses.JProcesses which internally uses WMI4Java to get the required information. But in this way I can get only the full command line to open the application while my requirement is to know exactly what file or what browser link is open.

Could somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use win32 functions to enumerate processes and windows and then package your interface in a dll and then use JNI.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample? That would be of much help. TIA.